# mysqli sorting query with multiple cases

Tags: mysql

can anyone explain the sorting order concept of the code given below: -

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN STATUS IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, currentstatus=3 DESC, X.addeddate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY  currentstatus=3  asc
```

result would be

```
3
1
2
4
5
6
```

another.....

```
ORDER BY  currentstatus=2 asc
```

result would be

```
2
1
3
4
5
6
```

If you apply a value on it, it prioritized the selected value. After that value is the remaining sort.